# Kaltura Android Reference app API. Autoplay ('doPlay') video on entryReady

Tags: java, android, api, kaltura

The case is rater simple. Am using kalturas [Android referance app](https://github.com/kaltura/AndroidReferenceApp) and i want my videos to auto play.

For this there is several API hooks: [Kaltura KDP API Compatibility](http://html5video.org/wiki/Kaltura_KDP_API_Compatibility)

What i come up to is that i want to use event **jsCallbackReady** and event listener **entryReady** to send notification **doPlay** and that i want to put this code in [PlayerViewController.java](https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android/blob/master/PlayerSDK/src/com/kaltura/playersdk/PlayerViewController.java)

The issue is that i can't get it to work, I can't grep how to work with this API within the reference application.Have tested uncountable setups and have searched every corner on internet to find any hands on information / examples that would get me going in the right direction but found nothing.

Really need someone to give a hands on example how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution to this was this code.

```
 final PlayerViewController  mPlayerView = (PlayerViewController) findViewById( R.id.custom_player );

 // Autoplay video
                  mPlayerView.registerJsCallbackReady(new KPlayerJsCallbackReadyListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void jsCallbackReady() {
                          mPlayerView.play();

                      }
                  });
```

Added [here (Github)](https://github.com/kaltura/AndroidReferenceApp/blob/780a07e97da9b54e04fdf396d3f2b0ca9cbba298/DemoApplication/src/com/kaltura/activity/Info.java#L216)

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste few of your code lines from what you have so far with the classes that you are using ?
If I'm not mistaken the code should be at the PlayerInterface rather than the PlayerView

Comment: Will update my post but until then see here if it make any sense https://github.com/kaltura/AndroidReferenceApp/issues/5